# Corrupted accented characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, utf-8

The response date from this url contains corrupted accented characters. Why? Fiddler shows them correctly! I imagine the problem is caused by UTF characters being incorrectly processed. By me, jQuery or IE? Unfortunately, I don't understand the principles behind UTF data processing! I have another query which returns JSON data. This works fine!

The code only works in IE! Not in Chrome, nor in Firefox. Is it a problem with CORS? Does anybody know a workaround for this?

```
var urlMag = 'http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0';
$.ajax({
    url: urlMag,
    context: {},
    success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
        },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log("error: " + e.responseText);
        }
    })
    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            console.log("done: " + data)
    });
```

---

### Here are the results:

In console.log special characters show differently than seen here. eg,  Programa (Programação) shows as ProgramaxEFxBFxBF, etc.

---

### Result shown by console.log

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">    
<head>    

<!-- Meta Tags -->    
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0" />    
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />    
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />    
<meta name="author" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta name="created" content="01/12/2015 07:23:36" />    
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="85553650775" />    
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="146944948751407" />    
<meta name="keywords" content="Guia de Programa, BBB, TV, televis cabo,
por assinatura, programa, guia, filme, se, seriado, m, variedades,
ero, novela, f, notas, jornalismo, informa, nota,
entretenimento, NET, SKY, TVA, DIRECTV, Telefa, Vivo, Globo, SBT, Record, S
```

---

### Result shown in textArea

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">    
<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->    
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0" />    
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />    
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />    
<meta name="author" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta name="created" content="01/12/2015 07:23:36" />    
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="85553650775" />    
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="146944948751407" />    
<meta name="keywords" content="Guia de Programa�, BBB, TV, televis� cabo, por assinatura, programa�, guia, filme, s�e, seriado, m�, variedades, er�o, novela, f�, not�as, jornalismo, informa�, not�a, entretenimento, NET, SKY, TVA, DIRECTV, Telef�a, Vivo, Globo, SBT, Record, SporTV, Big Brother, HBO, Telecine, ESPN, Band, PFC, Premiere, PPV, programa�, f�, youtube, v�o, v�os, widget, webslice, pay-per-view" />    
<meta property="og:article:author" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta property="og:description" content="Guia de Programa� da NET - TV Magazine. A TV Magazine �ais completo site sobre televis�do Brasil. Aqui voc�ncontra not�as, um completo guia de programa�, f� de discuss� v�os e muito mais." />    
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0" />     
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/imagens/png/touch_icon.png"/>    
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />    
<meta property="og:site_name" content="TV Magazine" />
```

### Result shown by Fiddler Web Debugger

```
GET http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0 HTTP/1.1    
Accept-Language: pt-BR    
Accept: */*    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko    
Host: www.tvmagazine.com.br    
DNT: 1    
Connection: Keep-Alive    
Pragma: no-cache


HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Connection: close    
Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 09:23:36 GMT    
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0    
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET    
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"    
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"    
Content-Length: 345726    
Content-Type: text/html    
Set-Cookie: tvmagazine=guia%5Faberto=1; path=/    
Set-Cookie: tvmagazine%2Dvmidtoken=; path=/    
Set-Cookie: tvmagazine%2Dvmid=; path=/    
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCSTQTSDC=FBKHFBHCKIEPJECDCCDECKAA; path=/    
Cache-control: private    

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">    
<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->    
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0" />    
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />    
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />    
<meta name="author" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta name="created" content="01/12/2015 07:23:36" />    
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="85553650775" />    
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="146944948751407" />    
<meta name="keywords" content="Guia de Programação, BBB, TV, televisão, cabo, por assinatura, programação, guia, filme, série, seriado, música, variedades, erótico, novela, fórum, notícias, jornalismo, informação, notícia, entretenimento, NET, SKY, TVA, DIRECTV, Telefônica, Vivo, Globo, SBT, Record, SporTV, Big Brother, HBO, Telecine, ESPN, Band, PFC, Premiere, PPV, programação, fórum, youtube, vídeo, vídeos, widget, webslice, pay-per-view" />    
<meta property="og:article:author" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta property="og:description" content="Guia de Programação da NET - TV Magazine. A TV Magazine é mais completo site sobre televisão do Brasil. Aqui você encontra notícias, um completo guia de programação, fórum de discussões, vídeos e muito mais." />    
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0" />     
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/imagens/png/touch_icon.png"/>    
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />    
<meta property="og:site_name" content="TV Magazine" />    
<meta property="og:title" content="Guia de Programação da NET - TV Magazine"/>
```

Comment: Are you using this code in a domain different than www.tvmagazine.com.br ? If so, this code won't work because of CORS. I just run it in my console and here's the result: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.tvmagazine.com.br/guia/programacao,NET,0?_=1448915742437. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`. You'll need to implement some CORS bypassing techniques

Comment: Your code seems fine to me (I just tested it in Chrome while on tvmagazine.com.br). Can you post the expected result? Is that the actual URL you're making the request to?

Comment: Have you checked that the HTTP response headers are correct? You might be sending UTF8 data, but the headers might be inidcating ASCII. Or vice-ersa.

Comment: Please see results posted above.

Comment: Eduardo, please see above "The code only works in IE! Not in Chrome, nor in Firefox". Please explain "some CORS bypassing techniques". Do you have a link?

Comment: nderscore, yes, this URL

Comment: uotonyh, I don´t understand your answer, please check the result from Fiddler and explain more. How do i check the HTTP response headers? Is this what Fiddler is showing?